# ERROR: file not found when using pytest with VSCode (macOS)

Tags: python, path, pytest, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a single unit test within `VSCode` by clicking `Run Test` (or `Debug Test`) above the unit test in the editor field, but I keep getting an `ERROR: file not found`:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.8, pytest-4.6.11, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: <path_to_project_root>/module_1, inifile: /<path_to_project_root>/module_1/setup.cfg
plugins: cov-2.12.1, mock-1.13.0, xdist-1.34.0, forked-1.3.0
collected 0 items

- generated xml file: /var/folders/j9/lmgwz_dj4y97dx0zzf8kdgmc0000gn/T/tmp-1161ZMgD73kgVd4v.xml -
========================= no tests ran in 0.15 seconds =========================
ERROR: file not found: ./module_1/src/tests/pipelines/clean/test_cleaning.py::test_cleaning
```

I suspect that this can be due to the fact that the current working directory,
(i.e. `.` in `ERROR: file not found: ./`) points to the `<path_to_project_root>/module_1` instead of `<path_to_project_root>`, but if I change the `cwd` setting in `settings.json`, VSCode stops discovering my tests.

My directory tree looks like this:

```
project_root/
├─ module_1/
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ tests/
│  ├─ setup.cfg
├─ module_2/
```

And some of (selected) settings defined in `settings.json`:

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["${workspaceFolder}/module_1/"],
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["${workspaceFolder}/module_1/"],
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled": true,
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "python.testing.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/module_1",
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": ["--rootdir","${workspaceFolder}/module_1"],
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true
}
```

My `.env` file:

```
PYTHONPATH="<path_to_project_root>/module_1/src/"
```

My question is essentially: **How can I resolve the `ERROR: file not found` error when running a single unit test in VSCode in such a (mono) repo?**

Side/auxiliary questions:

- How can I set the `pytest` current working directory to be `<path_to_project_root>` but still have VSCode discover my tests located inside `<path_to_project_root>/module_1/src/`?
- Alternatively, how can I keep the `cwd` to be `<path_to_project_root>/module_1` but tell VSCode not prepend a prefix `/module_1/` when looking for tests?
- How should `settings.json` look like to allow for seamless use of `pytest` inside the monorepo?

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not found an answer on how to get rid of an error, I have found a workaround - [Test Explorer UI plug-in](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-test-explorer) is able to both: discover unit tests in a monorepo, and run them without failing with the aforementioned error.